# iOS - Universal Links setup correctly but Smart Banner keeps appearing instead of automatically launching my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

This is driving me nuts. Universal Links are setup correctly in my app. If I place my universal link in a text message or email, and it's tapped by a user, it opens my app automatically. Hooray.

That said, if the user is sent to the Universal Link by clicking a link in a browser, it simply displays the Smart Banner at the top of the browser window and does not automatically open my app. I have a flow in which users setup their Stripe account with my app, and upon successful setup, I want it to direct the user back to my application (with my Universal Link).

I can't seem to accomplish this. Help is appreciated!!